# Matlab regexp; lookaround for either one of two expressions

Tags: regex, matlab, regex-lookarounds

I have a table with with a column full of strings of file names. 
The filenames come in different formats:

```
str ={... 
'filename',...
'filename_suffix',...
'filenamesuffix'};
```

I'm trying to use `regexp` to extract the *suffix* part of each filename (and receive `''` for the one without the suffix) using the code (note that the suffix can be any set of characters, including underscore):

```
regexp(str,'(?<=filename(_|)).*','match','emptymatch')
```

unfortunately, this gives me the output (after spreading the output cell):

```
ans = 

{''}


ans = 

'_suffix'


ans = 

'suffix'
```

specifically, it does not disregard the `_` in the second suffix as i would expect when writing `filename(_|)`, which I understand to be *try to match `filename_` and if not found try to match `filename`* but apparently I have misread that line.

could anyone help me achieve the *lookaround with either one of 2 options*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, Matlab regex, the lookbehind cannot have alternation inside an alternative branch.

Expand the pattern as

```
regexp(str,'(?<=filename_|filename).*','match','emptymatch')
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The `(?<=filename_|filename)` lookbehind will either require a `filename_` or `filename` to appear before 0+ chars other than a newline (`.*`). *However, the lookaround just checks the text without consuming it. You allow either `filename` or `filename_` to be right before the match. So, the engine checks the context on the left one char by one, and once it is equal to the `filename`, it matches the rest.

If you just need the suffix without `_`, you can use one of the following solutions:

```
ntoks = regexp(str, '(?<=filename_|filename)(?!_).*', 'match','emptymatch');
```

where the lookbehind is combined with a lookahead `(?!_)` that fails the match if there is a `_` after the current position (that means there will be no match in case of a `filename__sometext`), or

```
ntoks = regexp(str, 'filename_?(.*)', 'tokens','emptymatch');
```

where `_` is made optional with `?` quantifier.

To obtain the captured parts, you need to use `'tokens'`, not `'match'`. See [*Tokens in Regular Expressions*](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/tokens-in-regular-expressions.html).

See [demo](https://ideone.com/lN9SWH)

Comment: This is what I thought as well but `'filename_?(.*)'` still seems to match the entire string (i.e. it doesn't leave off `filename`

Comment: You need to get the *captured* part.

Comment: To do this you need to use `tokens` instead of `match`. See my answer for an example.

Comment: Certainly, [`tokens` should be used](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/tokens-in-regular-expressions.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com).

Comment: There is another solution actually, based on `match`. I added that solution, too.

Comment: Ok, there are 3 solutions, and I hope everything is clear now.

Comment: There are even more solutions (some of which don't need regex at all), but I believe that the choice of capturing the suffix and allowing empty matches is the best approach both for readability and performance.

Comment: @Skogsv: did you check the [`filename_?(.*)`](https://regex101.com/r/sG1gE2/2) vs. [`filename_?\K.*`](https://regex101.com/r/sG1gE2/1)? My suggestion with `\K` for *matching* is more efficient.

Comment: Moreover, `\K` is very readable since you do not need to see where the parentheses start or end: `\K` just signals that we *omit all before* and *keep what is matched after `\K`*.

Comment: I agree that `\K` saves one step in the regex process (13 vs 14 steps per match). I disagree that it is more readable (but that is personal preference).

Comment: Can I ask what version of matlab you've tested this in? I'm running `R2016a`on Windows  and it doesn't seem that `\K` is implemented. MATLAB does have a slimmed version of REGEX (e.g. impossible to capture groups in groups)

Comment: Well, that is interesting. I seems that Octave instance I tested it on is built with PCRE. I remove that example then since it seems there is no `\K` support in Matlab. Ok, a capturing group remains the most efficient way - I have also been preaching that approach: if there is no need to use lookarounds, use capturing groups. You may

Answer (score 3):

Another approach with less computation time could be achieved by using the outkey `tokens` and a capturing group instead:

```
str ={'filename','filename_suffix','filenamesuffix'};

result=regexp(str,'filename_?(.*)','tokens','emptymatch','once');

celldisp(result)
```

*Note:
I added the `'once'` option since each cell in the cellstring only seems the have a single filename in it. If you chose to remove it the result will be a cell array of cell arrays.*